# How to find a result from four tables based on keywords and the last time the result was found

Tags: php, mysql, keyword

Okay so I have these four tables: `links`, `submissions`, `links_keywords`, and `submissions_keywords`.

They are structured somewhat like this:

```
links:
link_id link_url

submissions:
submission_id submission_url submission_last_used

links_keywords:
id link_id keyword

submissions_keywords:
id submission_id keyword
```

What I want to do, is pull a result from submissions, where the keywords of a link best matches the keywords of the submission and if there is multiple results then to filter it by the result that was last used. I am unsure to how to structure this query. Also I do not want to match it with one keyword, I want to see how many keywords match and from there I can determine the best result.

Comment: Have you tried joined queries?

Comment: I wouldn't know how I would go about it, matching every keywords from links_keywords to submissions_keywords and finding the best results with the most matches. I can imagine doing quite a few queries to maybe accomplish this but I can't imagine it being great performance?

Comment: @Muggles: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @Muggles `SELECT * FROM links_keywords JOIN submissions_keywords ON links_keywords.keyword = submissions_keywords` Take a look at the results of this query. I think this'll give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on a similar query in Oracle.  It is 100% easier in MySQL because Oracle does not have a LIMIT clause. This may not be the most efficient, but will get you the answer you need.  To get the link value, simply add another join.  You can search for a single term by removing one of the keyword clauses.

```
select  
    t1.submission_id, t1.submission_url, t1.submission_last_used , t3.keyword
from 
    submissions t1
join submission_keywords t2 on 
    t2.submission_id = t1.submission_id
join link_keywords t3 on 
    t3.keyword = t2.keyword 
where 
    (t3.keyword = 'search' OR
    t3.keyword = 'email')
    AND t1.submission_id = (
        SELECT submission_id from submissions where submission_id IN (
            SELECT submission_id from submission_keywords WHERE keyword = t2.keyword) 
        order by submission_last_used DESC LIMIT 1);
```